# HTML table span, 2 row restricted to first column - css fix possible?

Tags: html, css

Interesting problem.  I have this code:

```
 <table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                 col1
             </td>
             <td>
                 col2
             </td>
             <td>
                 col3
             </td>
             <td>
                 col4
             </td>
       </tr>
       <tr style="display: block;">
             <td colspan="4">
                 in ie 11 text only appears in col1
             </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Now if this is rendered in IE 11 (or Chrome) the span is broken and the 2nd row is restricted to the first column.

The challenge is I **cannot** change the html code.  I'm looking for **CSS only** fix that could be applied to elements of the table structure?

Appreciate that this might not be possible, but be interested to know one way or the other.

Comment: hi remove  style="display: block;" block code it will work fine

Comment: `<tr style="display: block;">`??? why? If you need this tr to be with display: block; <table> is not the correct html element you need...

Comment: OP says cannot change HTML - why suggest it?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
table tr:nth-child(2) {
    display: table-row !important;
}
```

If there are multiple rows with the same condition then you can force all rows to behave as they should with:

```
table tr { 
    display: table-row !important; 
}
```

Comment: what if there will be multiple rows with `display:block`?

Comment: `table tr {
    display: table-row !important;
}` will force all rows to behave as they should